# Entering superscript text (exponents) in TextEdit?

Tags: imac, textedit

I am writing math problems on my iMac and I am using TextEdit. I need to add exponents to one of my problems. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can superscript style any text by highlighting the text and then selecting `Format -> Font -> Baseline -> Superscript` from the menu in TextEdit.

It's not assigned to a keyboard shortcut by default. To assign it to a keyboard shortcut go to `System Preferences -> Keyboard` and click on the `Keyboard Shortcuts` tab. Select `Application Shortcuts` from the left hand list and press the `+` button button below the right hand list to add a new application-specific shortcut:

[image]

From the menu that pops up select `TextEdit` as the application (otherwise the shortcut will be made for all applications). For `Menu Title` enter `Format->Font->Baseline->Superscript` and for `Keyboard Shortcut` (assuming OS X 10.8 or higher). Put your cursor in the box and press the combination of keys you want to use for the shortcut (I used Cmd+Shift+= in my screen capture example):

[image]

Press `Add` button to store the shortcut. You might have to restart TextEdit for the shortcut to appear.

Comment: Thanks! Will this work on all word-processing software?

Comment: It's application specific.

Answer (score 3):

### Modify the Press & Hold keys

For entering numbers in superscript (exponents), I prefer the Press & Hold method since it works in any app regardless of whether the app supports it (e.g. plain-text editors).

1. Navigate to `System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/Resources/`.
2. Backup the `Keyboard-en.plist` file.
3. Append the following to the `Keyboard-en.plist` file (before the closing `</dict></plist>`).

   ```
   <key>Roman-Accent-t</key>
   <dict>
       <key>Direction</key>
       <string>right</string>
       <key>Keycaps</key>
       <string>t ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹ ⁰</string>
       <key>Strings</key>
       <string>t ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹ ⁰</string>
   </dict>
   ```

Feel free to change the `Roman-Accent-t` to any character you wish, providing it does not already have Press & Hold keys assigned.

Comment: One disadvantage of this method is that it may not look good with all fonts and you are limited to the characters you have put into the .plist.  Exponents can have things other than numbers in them.

Comment: Another disadvantage is that you have to disable SIP to do it.  And a third is that Software Update will remove your changes.  (Also, it seems that Apple has changed the path to the file at least three times and changed the format from XML to binary.